# Undefined class 'CurrentUser'

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

CurrentUser is undefine I am trying to figure out what has it changed to.If you know plz help

***It's says Could not find the correct Provider above this Screen Widget***

```
CurrentUser _currentUser = Provider.of<CurrentUser>(context, listen: false);
```

Comment: *When using the `of` method, the context must be a descendant of the InheritedWidget, meaning it must be "below" the InheritedWidget in the tree*. Ie. you don't have a `Provider<CurrentUser>` above the widget you're making the call from. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InheritedWidget-class.html

Answer (score 0):

Initialize all your providers before materialApp, so you can access them

```
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
            value: Auth(),
          ),
          ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
            value: CurrentUser(),
          ),
        ],
        child: MaterialApp(
          home: HomePage(),
     ),);
  }
}
```

Comment: It says that  'dynamic' doesn't conform to the bound 'ChangeNotifier?' of the type parameter 'T'.
Try using a type that is or is a subclass of 'ChangeNotifier?'.

Comment: Did you inherit 'ChangeNotifier' for your CurrentUser like this: class MyUser with ChangeNotifier {} ?